# Can't get SFML Music to work

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

Okay, just a forewarning: I am really new to C++ and only began coding this year.

So, I have been trying to code this program to run in the console using the SFML libraries. I had problems in the past trying to get the libraries to work, but now I'm good. So, I have a function that plays music, but when I try to activate the function in the console I just get a return value of 0 and the console closes.

Relevant code:

```
void music ()
{
      system("CLS");

      sf::Music WorldOnFire;

      std::string musicInput;

      std::cout << "What would you like to listen to?" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "> Track 1 - \"I Don't Want to Set the World on Fire\" by The Ink Spots" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "> Back" << std::endl;

      std::getline(std::cin, musicInput);

      std::transform(musicInput.begin(), musicInput.end(), musicInput.begin(), ::toupper);
      musicInput.erase(std::remove(musicInput.begin(), musicInput.end(), ' '), musicInput.end());

      if (musicInput == "TRACK1" || musicInput == "TRACK1-\"IDON'TWANTTOSETTHEWORLDONFIRE\"" || musicInput == "TRACK1-\"IDON'TWANTTOSETTHEWORLDONFIRE\"BYTHEINKSPOTS" || musicInput == "\"IDON'TWANTTOSETTHEWORLDONFIRE\"" || musicInput == "IDON'TWANTTOSETTHEWORLDONFIRE")
      {
          if (!WorldOnFire.openFromFile("WorldOnFire.ogg"))
          {
               std::cout << "Could not open file. File corrupted or missing." << std::endl;
               std::cin.ignore();
               music();
          }
          WorldOnFire.play();
      }

      else if (musicInput == "BACK")
      {
          system("CLS");
          activitypage ();
      }
}
```

Here is all the code, with omissions for personal reasons. [Source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82f6eca4eaaf0ad04192)

Comment: are you waiting after you issue the play? Because music runs in paralel to main thread(it would be silly to have main thread blocked until music stopped)

Comment: @Creris I'm unsure what you mean. I included the entire program above if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorldOnFire.play();` is non blocking. Therefore your program will terminate before any sound is actually played.

You need to add some kind of loop in your application. It can be as simple as a greedy while(isPlaying):

```
while (WorldOnFire.getStatus() == sf::Music::Playing);
```

or a bit more energy-efficient:

```
sf::sleep(WorldOnFire.getDuration() - WorldOnFire.getPlayingOffset());
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. If you could, can you tell me what that means? The non-blocking? Also, if I wanted to let the user pause or stop the music, would I just have a cin after the while?

Comment: @YuriKircovich it means, as I said in my comment, that it will start running in separate thread and it will not block execution of your code. So your code inside main happily continues to run. To understand this a bit more, you would have to learn a bit about threads.

Comment: @YuriKircovich, @Creris just said everything about non blocking. ;-) You could use `cin` to let the user give some instruction but honestly it will be a mess to code... you'd better learn how to use the window and graphics module of SFML.

Comment: @Hiura Yeah, I assume it would be easier that way, but I wanted to code it in the console to give it that retro feeling. Going for a Fallout look. Could also do that with graphics, but I wasn't planing on that.